# ways to check a certificate fingerprint against known logs

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation, sha256, certificate-transparency

Suppose I have a certificate sha-256 fingerprint, which I can obtain say visiting the relevant domain in firefox or from a shell script using openssl, and i want to verify this fingerprint. one option is to look up the domain name on `https://crt.sh` and see if the fingerprints for the certificate match, but should i trust such site? ultimately i think so, as its source is on github, and what it probably does is pull the logs from google aviator and similar, but do you guys know more? or are there any similar ones that are trusted? (for example google certificate transparency does not seem to provide the fingerprint.)

Comment: did you want to fetch the fingerprint/cert from the remote host itself?

Comment: @dandavis No, I wanted to check it against an 'independent' source.

Comment: There are no sites "that are trusted". Either you trust a site or you don't trust it. Why should you trust any site we we recommend here but not `crt.sh`? What must a site have that you can trust it?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich a good certificate? :) just joking, i guess you're right, it's a kind of pointless question.